# And Engine : SVG - Android Vertices Helper

Tags: android, svg, andengine

I am making a game which requires to use of SVGs and I cannot figure out how to assign custom vertices(Shape) to my SVG image for its Body.When I was using pngs instead of SVGs then I was able to give the exact vertices dor the body with the help of Android Vertices Helper but now with Svgs the vertices from AVhelper are giving me abnormal results.Its actually giving me a very large body as compared to its image.Any help would be highly appreciated.